# MacOS 10.14 Mojave public beta captive portal Wi-Fi issue

Tags: macos, network, wifi, beta, mojave

I can not connect to a public Wi-Fi hotspot that does not require a password but instead shows a captive portal pop-up window.  The pop-up opens blank with the error "The web page couldn't be loaded" ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUKyl.png)) This is with Mojave Public Beta (18A314K) on a 2017 15" MBP.

I did see [this page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329163/macos-10-14-mojave-public-beta-public-wi-fi-problem) but the solution there did not work for me.

Specifically - When I go to http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html in Safari (v. 12.0, 14606.1.20.40.3), I just see text in the upper left corner of the webpage saying "Success" (minus the quotes) in an otherwise plain white background. If I open a new tab and try browsing, nothing loads saying there's no internet connection. If I open Chrome (v. 67.0.3396.99 64-bit), I also get no internet connection.

How can I tell if I'm getting a valid IP address or if this is a bug in my build that I could work around?

Comment: Be sure to let Apple know via the channels they have for beta testers.  Presumably things like this will get fixed in one of the many beta updates you will get between now and October.

Comment: @fsb I would add a bounty but my reputation isn't high enough. I just joined the site. Also see my edit as to "why my question is different" from your link.

Comment: @TomGewecke I did that as well.

Comment: Seeing this currently with a client's machine just updated to Mojave - wasn't fixed in beta.