# Cannot connect to public Wi-Fi: "a problem occurred"

Tags: mac, wifi, mojave, error

Every time I try to connect to a public Wi-Fi with a login (train station, hotel), my Mac (macOS 10.14.4) connects but generates an error when asking for the credentials:

[image: Wi-Fi login window with error message]

Rebooting does not solve the problem. Any idea what I could try?

Comment: Try opening this URL in Safari: http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html

Comment: @NimeshNeema No connection, the browser just waits.

Comment: @NimeshNeema how can you copy the address into safari. I have found no way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cmd + Spacebar, Open System Preferences -> Network -> Wifi -> Advanced -> DNS

In the DNS section, remove all the DNS addresses and search domains and apply the new settings, so that the public wifi could use the one that it is configured with.

Answer (score -2):

Because normally Apple approves the only secure connection. So the connection is not secure to connect.

Comment: Yes, but there should be an authentication page which appears regardless of secure connection.